# Pandas Series str split method breaks with negative lookahead

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a Pandas Series from which I want to extract some information. The series looks like below:

```
import pandas as pd
ex = {0: 'A_26_y',
 1: 'A_25_x',
 2: 'B_3_x',
 3: 'A_17_y',
 4: 'B_11_x',
 5: 'A_19_y',
 6: 'A_17_y',
 7: 'A_18_x',
 8: 'C_x',
 9: 'B_12_y'}
ex = pd.Series(ex)

ex
0    A_26_y
1    A_25_x
2     B_3_x
3    A_17_y
4    B_11_x
5    A_19_y
6    A_17_y
7    A_18_x
8       C_x
9    B_12_y
dtype: object
```

I want to break the Series on second occurance of `_` sign. I tried to use negative lookahead like below:

```
ex.str.split(r"(_)(?!.*\1)", expand=True)
```

However, it results in 3 columns, and not 2 as I would expect, as it returns also the separator:

```
    0   1   2
0   A_26    _   y
1   A_25    _   x
2   B_3     _   x
3   A_17    _   y
4   B_11    _   x
5   A_19    _   y
6   A_17    _   y
7   A_18    _   x
8   C       _   x
9   B_12    _   y
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: `r"_(?!.*_)"`, or `r"_(?=[^_]*$)"`. Do not capture the `_`.

Comment: how about ex.str.split("_",expand=True) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid `regex` and use [`Series.str.rsplit`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rsplit.html) with `n=1`:

```
In [533]: ex.str.rsplit('_', n=1, expand=True)
Out[533]: 
      0  1
0  A_26  y
1  A_25  x
2   B_3  x
3  A_17  y
4  B_11  x
5  A_19  y
6  A_17  y
7  A_18  x
8     C  x
9  B_12  y
```